# Switch a condenser dryer from drawer to pipe

Tags: electrical, dryer, appliances, 240v

How does one switch a condenser (ventless) dryer such as the Electrolux edc78550w from collecting the water in the drawer to pushing it through the back pipe?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before.  On the back of my machine there was a drain plug and I simply attached a hose to this and ran the other down the drain in the floor.

On my machine the drawer was located at the top of the machine so there was actually a little pump that pumped the water from below up to the drawer. If you don't have a drain in the floor you might have to use a hose going from this pump.

Comment: Thanks. I see a red pipe coming out of the back of the machine close to the top. How does the dryer know when to pump through it, and when to use the drawer? In other words, why does it not always drip through it? (I don't have enough reputation to upvote).

Comment: On my machine it was very easy to take off the various body panels to see what was going on. The main point is water doesn't go uphill, so depending on where your drain is you need to tap in to the system so you can get rid of the water. I think all dryers have a drain plug low down somewhere in on the machine, so if you have a drain in the floor or can raise the machine a little you could also use that. I had a drain in the floor so I used that one because it was the easiest to access and it meant that there was never any water for the pump to send to the tray.

Comment: Thanks. But I do have a drain. The question is - the dryer doesn't know whether or not I attached a pipe to the short pipe protruding from the top of the machine. So how does it know whether to push water through that pipe or not?

Comment: The condensate pumps usually have a check valve so once they pump the water is out the tube, a sensor or a float activate the pump once the water level drops the pump shuts off. The check valve holds the water in the pipe but worse case it drains back into the pan and continues to fill until the switch turns the pump back on.